# Верстка адаптивного меню

Tags: html, css

В данный момент верстаю адаптивное меню, и у меня возникла проблема. То есть, мои ссылки белого цвета (когда страница в разрешении 980px), но когда я кликаю по гамбургер меню, то они раскрываются, но они не того цвета, которые были изначально. Скажите пожалуйста, как можно решить подобную проблему?

Comment: откройте дев тулс и посмотрите какие стили применяются на этот элемент в открытом состоянии. Возможно там при открытии навешивается какой-то клас

Answer (score 0):

Переопределить стили, которые сейчас для них действуют. Смотрите в дебагере и перепрописывайте на свои.